# Bumped version on git private repo and now install requirements fail

Tags: python, git, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

I have access to a git repo that implements a dependency that I'm using in my project. Naturally, this dependency is in my requirements.txt like this:

```
git+https://HASH@github.com/repowner/dependency_name.git@v0.1.4
```

It always worked fine, but recently I needed to make some changes in the dependency, so I opened a pull request and got it reviewed by my teacher (repo owner) before merging it. In this PR I also bumped the version, and did just like a previous PR(from another author). All I changed was a changelog file that is pure text and the `setup.py`:

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="dependency_name",
    version='0.1.5', #<<< Only changed this from 0.1.4 to 0.1.5
    description="Desc",
    license='...',
    platforms=['OS Independent'],
    keywords='...',
    author='...',
    url="https://github.com/repoowner/dependency_name",
    packages=find_packages()
)
```

I assumed this was enough (as it was done like this before). I've updated my `requirements.txt` to:

```
git+https://HASH@github.com/repowner/dependency_name.git@v0.1.5
```

But now, when I try to `pip install -r requirements.txt` I get:

```
Collecting git+https://****@github.com/repoowner/dependency_name.git@v0.1.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Cloning https://****@github.com/repoowner/dependency_name.git (to revision v0.1.5) to /tmp/pip-req-build-fvq5k_04
  Running command git clone -q 'https://****@github.com/repoowner/dependency_name.git' /tmp/pip-req-build-fvq5k_04
  WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'v0.1.5', assuming revision or ref.
  Running command git checkout -q v0.1.5
  error: pathspec 'v0.1.5' did not match any file(s) known to git
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q v0.1.5 Check the logs for full command output.
```

Did I missed something when trying to bump the version?

BTW: If I try the 0.1.4 it installs without my recent changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to tag the PR/merge commit with `v0.1.5` tag, as suggested by the error message:

```
WARNING: Did not find branch or tag 'v0.1.5', assuming revision or ref.
```

You can confirm this by listing existing tags with the command `git tag`.

To create and push the tag:

- Use the command `git log` (you can add `--pretty=oneline` to get an easier-to-read output) and find the hash of your most recent commit that you would like to be included in the `v0.1.5` tag/version
- Create the new tag with the command `git tag -a v0.1.5 <hash_of_your_commit>`
- Push the new tag with `git push --tags`

See [git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) about basic usage of tags

See [git docs for `git tag` subcommand](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag)

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem! Just to clarify, in a ideal situation I should do this in the branch I'm working before merging the PR, or just apply the tags after merging?

Comment: @ZeCarioca If you are working only with your branch and the master branch I don't think it matters. If you are working with other branches as well you will have to do that after the merge so the tag will contain the other needed commits from the other branches